# IOS Parent-Child Frame Change issue

Tags: ios, uitextview, frame

I am trying to resize a `UITextView` bottom aligned and its parent view and below is my code:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
CGSize newTextViewSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(kTextViewFixedWidth, kTextViewMaxHeight)];

if( newTextViewSize.height != self.textViewOldHeight )
{

    CGRect newTextViewFrame = textView.frame;

    newTextViewFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newTextViewSize.width, kTextViewFixedWidth), newTextViewSize.height);

    CGPoint sizeDiff = CGPointMake(newTextViewFrame.size.width-textView.frame.size.width, newTextViewFrame.size.height-textView.frame.size.height);
    newTextViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(textView.frame.origin.x, textView.frame.origin.y-sizeDiff.y);


    self.textViewOldHeight = newTextViewFrame.size.height;

    CGRect newViewFrame = self.frame;
    newViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y-sizeDiff.y);
    newViewFrame.size = CGSizeMake( self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height+sizeDiff.y);
    self.frame = newViewFrame;

    textView.frame = newTextViewFrame;


}
```

Here what I tried to do is calculate the size change for textView then apply that change to view that is its parent-which is self-. What happens is self resizes but textView resets. However when I commended out the part where self resize happened, child textview worked as expected. Can anyone direct me in the right direction to find what is wrong here?

Thanks and have fun...

While looking into the case i wrote the below code:

```
-(void)resize
{
    self.subView = ((UIView*)[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0]);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{

                         CGRect newSubViewFrame = self.subView.frame;
                         newSubViewFrame.size.height += 100;
                         self.subView.frame = newSubViewFrame;
                         NSLog(@"%f", self.subView.frame.size.height);

                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              NSLog(@"%f", self.subView.frame.size.height);
                                              CGRect newSuperViewFrame = self.frame;
                                              newSuperViewFrame.origin.y -= 50;
                                              newSuperViewFrame.size.height += 100;
                                              self.frame = newSuperViewFrame;
                                              NSLog(@"%f", self.subView.frame.size.height);

                                          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                          }];
                 }];
    NSLog(@"%f", self.subView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Story is i have a super(red) and subview(black) and when the code runs sub view first grows as I intended. However when super view starts to resize sub view resets its size and logs all returned 150. So any idea how to fix it?

[image: Red is superview black is child]

Comment: If `self` is the parent of `textView`, then the coordinates of `textView` are relative to the coordinates of `self`. Which means that if you change the Y coordinate of both the frames of `self` and `textView`, you probably move the `textView` twice as far as you want... Try removing only the line where you set `newTextViewFrame.origin`.

Comment: @Guillaume thanks for the heads up but resizing issue still holds.

Comment: can u try a [textview setneeddisplay] after condition check.

Comment: @imalvare i did but didnt work.

Comment: It was a  auto layout problem. Solved by disabling auto layout. If anyone happens to know any solution please send a post.